Upon burial, Staying at Grave of Father in Law and reciting for some time?
Assalam o Alaikum!
Recently my father in law passed away, and my wife asked me to be at his grave upon burial on her behalf and recite for some time as reflected from posts about the time taken for camel slaughter.
I did so because of her will as well as I had a very deep good bond with my father in law.
Normally I don't debate over matters I have less knowledge. My friends upon hearing it told me your reciting would not benefit your father in law. I just couldn't accept it as of the basic core of Islam I understand. So I just wanted to ask those with diverse knowledge that being son in law, if I took a part with every single thing in the funeral. Procession and after burying i stayed there for almost 2 hours and recited. Will it benefit my deceased father in law?
JazakAllah
Regards
Nouman Ahmed Khan (40 years, Pakistan)

@UmH so your link implies that it does not make a difference if the daughter or the son in law would do the reciting? From your link, I gather that it doesn't matter who does the reciting, but only the schools of Islam differ if it any effect at all. Between the lines I gues it is not haram to try. Is that so? Please explain.

A person can recite the Quran and receive reward himself. There is difference on whether he can then gift this reward to someone else (such as a deceased). Among those who allow it, it does not matter who the gifter is, when it is permitted for anyone in general then it is also permitted for X in particular.
